# Unmatched '. in awk

Tags: awk, csh

I am running a script containing this code in Ubuntu:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
set file = $1
if ($1! == "" ) then
awk '{ \
if ( NR == 1 ) NCOLS = $2; \
if ( NR == 2 ) NROWS = $2; \
if ( NR == 3 ) LL_LNG = $2; \
if ( NR == 4 ) LL_LAT = $2; \
if ( NR == 5 ) CELLSIZE = $2; \
if ( NR == 6 ) NODATA = $2; \
if ( NR > 6 ) { \
for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++ ) { \
if ( $i! == NODATA ) { \
printf("%f %f %f\n", LL_LNG + (i-1) * CELLSIZE + CELLSIZE / 2, LL_LAT + (NROWS-(NR-7)) * CELLSIZE - CELLSIZE / 2, $i ) \
#printf("%f %f %f\n" LL_LNG + (i-1) * CELLSIZE, LL_LAT + (NROWS-(NR-7)) * CELLSIZE, $i ) \
} \
} \
} \
}' $file
endif
```

I run it as a `.sh` file with the `csh` command and the error it gives is:

```
Unmatched '.
```

Can anybody help me to find out what the error is in this code and how to correct it?

Comment: Is it possible to now what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a ascii file of latitude and longitude and I want to extract latitude and longitude from that by csh command.

Comment: In order to let me test your script, is it possible to have a part of the file that you are parsing? Change values if there is any personal or confidential data.

Comment: How to send it sir?If there is any email address?

Comment: Best is using http://pastebin.com (or any similar website), then edit your post with the generated link.

Comment: AFAIK, in both `csh` and `awk`, inequality is tested using the `!=` operator i.e.  `thing1 != thing2` - not `thing1! == thing2` as you have

Comment: I tried if ($1 != "") then but same error is coming

Comment: Unmatched '. come for what that is not getting.

Comment: It still looks like a `csh` error not an `awk` error, to me - however I can't reproduce it (at least, not with `tcsh`). I still don't understand why you are wrapping your `awk` in a `csh` script (or a shell script of any flavor, for that matter). Have you tried simplifying it down and testing the `awk` code on its own?

Comment: Does this error always occur, or only with that particular data file? I am also unable to make this happen, with both `bsd-csh` and `tcsh` on Ubuntu 16.04, but I still think it's more likely to be happening in a way that doesn't depend on contents of the input file. Can you produce an input file where this error occurs but which is small enough to include in your question? What is the actual full command you are using to run the script? If you run `csh` and then paste in the command starting with `awk` and ending in `}'` (but not the `$file` part) and press Enter,  do you get `Unmatched '`?

Comment: yes I write a command csh csh1.scr test.txt